# Specify minimal lines for Text in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

For various reasons a `Text` should always have at least the height equal to `x` lines of text, no matter if it has less than x lines of text. The `Text` and `BasicText` Composables only have a `maxLines` parameter but no `minLines`

I have tried the following (x = 3):

```
Text(
    modifier = Modifier.sizeIn(minHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) {
       (42*3).sp.toDp()
    }),
    color = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
    text = "Sample", textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h2 /* fontSize = 42 */,
    lineHeight = 42.sp
)
```

The resulting height is less than if the text would contain 3 lines

Back in View World Android, we could simply use `minLines=3`, how can we achieve this in Jetpack Compose?

Comment: oh so you specify the `lineHeight` and then the "minLines" is `lineHeight * (number of lines)` set as a minimal height to the modifier

Comment: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/layouts/intrinsic-measurements

Answer (score 12):

Your code is almost correct, just set **lineHeight** to **fontSize*4/3**:

```kotlin
var lineHeight = MaterialTheme.typography.h2.fontSize*4/3

Text(
    modifier = Modifier.sizeIn(minHeight = with(LocalDensity.current) {
       (lineHeight*3).toDp()
    }),
    color = MaterialTheme.colors.onPrimary,
    text = "Sample", textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h2,
    lineHeight = lineHeight
)
```

But you can do something similar without calculations using **onTextLayout** callback:

```
fun main() = Window {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("Hello, World!") }
    var lines by remember { mutableStateOf(0) }

    MaterialTheme {
        Button(onClick = {
            text += "\nnew line"
        }) {
            Column {
                Text(text,
                    maxLines = 5,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.h2,
                    onTextLayout = { res -> lines = res.lineCount })
                for (i in lines..2) {
                    Text(" ", style = MaterialTheme.typography.h2)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where does the value 4/3 come from?

Comment: @M.Wojcik `pt` to `px` conversion 1pt = 4/3px

Comment: worked with me  thanks

Answer (score 10):

Starting from M2 `1.4.0-alpha02` and M3 `1.1.0-alpha02` you can use the **`minLines`** attribute in the `Text`:

```
   Text(
       text = "MinLines = 3",
       modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth().background(Yellow),
       minLines = 3
   )
```

[image]

Note that `minLines` is the minimum height in terms of minimum number of visible lines. It is required that `1 <= minLines <= maxLines`.

You can use it with M2 and M3.

Comment: FYI: google tracker for this feature request
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122476634

Answer (score 7):

While we are [waiting for Google implements this feature](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/122476634) you can use this workaround:

```kotlin
@Preview
@Composable
fun MinLinesPreview() {
    lateinit var textLayoutResult: TextLayoutResult

    val text = "Title\ntitle\nTITLE\nTitle"
//    val text = "title\ntitle\ntitle\ntitle"
//    val text = "title\ntitle"
//    val text = "title"

    Text(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        text = text.addEmptyLines(3), // ensures string has at least N lines,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        maxLines = 4,
    )
}

fun String.addEmptyLines(lines: Int) = this + "\n".repeat(lines)
```

Now your `Text` has the same height regardless string content:

[image: Text height with 1 line]
[image: Text height with 2 lines]
[image: Text height with 4 lines]
[image: Text height with 4 lines with capslock]

This solution is much more easier than calculate `Text`'s bottom offset based on line height in `onTextLayout` (spoiler: start, center and last line have different height)

Comment: Neat idea! However, there are two problems with this approach. When using ellipsize it will even add "..." if the text would actually fit into the 4 lines. Also, the height of the `\n` lines won't be equal to a regular line resulting in a Text element with lesser height than a "regular" one with 4 lines all occupied with regular characters.

Answer (score 3):

If **one additional recomposition of the `Text`** is fine for you, you can also make use of the `onTextLayout` callback of `Text` as a workaround until there is official support for minimum lines from Google:

```kotlin
val minLineCount = 4
var text by remember { mutableStateOf(description) }
Text(
    text = text,
    maxLines = minLineCount, // optional, if you want the Text to always be exactly 4 lines long
    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis, // optional, if you want ellipsizing
    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
    onTextLayout = { textLayoutResult ->
        // the following causes a recomposition if there isn't enough text to occupy the minimum number of lines!
        if ((textLayoutResult.lineCount) < minLineCount) {
            // don't forget the space after the line break, otherwise empty lines won't get full height!
            text = description + "\n ".repeat(minLineCount - textLayoutResult.lineCount) 
        }
    },
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
)
```

This will also properly work with ellipsizing and any kind of font padding, line height style etc. settings your heart desires.

A "fake" 4-line Text (with, say, 2 empty lines at the end) will have the same height like a "real" 4 line Text with 4 fully occupied lines of text. This oftentimes can be super important when e.g. laying out multiple `wrap_content`-height cards horizontally next to each other and the Text (in combination with `maxLines`) should determine the height of the cards, while all cards should have the same height (and it should work in regular *and* tall languages, like Burmese).

*Please note, that this will not work in Android Studio's preview. My guess is, that Studio doesn't allow recompositions in the preview for performance reasons.*

Comment: What is exactLineCount?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS my bad, I've fixed the sample. It should actually say `minLineCount`.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a solution that I came up with that will set the height to a specific number of lines (you could adapt the modifier to make it minLines) It is inspired by code found from the compose SDK

```
// Inspiration: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/6075c715aea671a616890dd7f0fc9a50d96e75b9/compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/MaxLinesHeightModifier.kt#L38
fun Modifier.minLinesHeight(
minLines: Int,
textStyle: TextStyle
) = composed {
val density = LocalDensity.current
val layoutDirection = LocalLayoutDirection.current

val resolvedStyle = remember(textStyle, layoutDirection) {
    resolveDefaults(textStyle, layoutDirection)
}
val resourceLoader = LocalFontLoader.current

val heightOfTextLines = remember(
    density,
    textStyle,
    layoutDirection
) {
    val lines = (EmptyTextReplacement + "\n").repeat(minLines - 1)

    computeSizeForDefaultText(
        style = resolvedStyle,
        density = density,
        text = lines,
        maxLines = minLines,
        resourceLoader
    ).height
}

val heightInDp: Dp = with(density) { heightOfTextLines.toDp() }
val heightToSet = heightInDp + OutlinedTextBoxDecoration

Modifier.height(heightToSet)
}

// Source: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/6075c715aea671a616890dd7f0fc9a50d96e75b9/compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/TextFieldDelegate.kt#L61
fun computeSizeForDefaultText(
style: TextStyle,
density: Density,
text: String = EmptyTextReplacement,
maxLines: Int = 1,
resourceLoader: Font.ResourceLoader
): IntSize {
val paragraph = Paragraph(
    paragraphIntrinsics = ParagraphIntrinsics(
        text = text,
        style = style,
        density = density,
        resourceLoader = resourceLoader
    ),

    maxLines = maxLines,
    ellipsis = false,
    width = Float.POSITIVE_INFINITY
)

return IntSize(paragraph.minIntrinsicWidth.ceilToIntPx(), paragraph.height.ceilToIntPx())
}

// Source: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/6075c715aea671a616890dd7f0fc9a50d96e75b9/compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/TextFieldDelegate.kt#L47
internal const val DefaultWidthCharCount = 10
internal val EmptyTextReplacement = "H".repeat(DefaultWidthCharCount)

// Needed because paragraph only calculates the height to display the text and not the entire height
// to display the decoration of the TextField Widget
internal val OutlinedTextBoxDecoration = 40.dp

// Source: https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/6075c715aea671a616890dd7f0fc9a50d96e75b9/compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/TextDelegate.kt#L296
internal fun Float.ceilToIntPx(): Int = ceil(this).roundToInt()
```

Additional discussion on this implementation and other options can be found here:

https://kotlinlang.slack.com/archives/CJLTWPH7S/p1621789835172600

Comment: Thanks man! Works well on TextField, but unfortunately not as well on Text. I will have to implement some other solution for Text.

Comment: @intips - google has made updates to the compose repo to provide similar support - maybe this will work for you https://github.com/androidx/androidx/blob/7c52194062c6035fe0685da48d239116d41c859a/compose/foundation/foundation/src/commonMain/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/text/HeightInLinesModifier.kt#L46

Comment: Perfect, thanks a lot! Now this one works for Text only. But my problem is solved anyway. I think this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

### create custom Text

it doesn't work in @Preview but the runtime

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MinLineText(
    text: String,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    color: Color = Color.Unspecified,
    fontSize: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    fontStyle: FontStyle? = null,
    fontWeight: FontWeight? = null,
    fontFamily: FontFamily? = null,
    letterSpacing: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    textDecoration: TextDecoration? = null,
    textAlign: TextAlign? = null,
    lineHeight: TextUnit = TextUnit.Unspecified,
    overflow: TextOverflow = TextOverflow.Clip,
    softWrap: Boolean = true,
    maxLines: Int = Int.MAX_VALUE,
    minLines: Int = 0,
    onTextLayout: (TextLayoutResult) -> Unit = {},
    style: TextStyle = LocalTextStyle.current
) {
    var mText by remember { mutableStateOf(text) }

    Text(
        mText,
        modifier,
        color,
        fontSize,
        fontStyle,
        fontWeight,
        fontFamily,
        letterSpacing,
        textDecoration,
        textAlign,
        lineHeight,
        overflow,
        softWrap,
        maxLines,
        {
            if (it.lineCount < minLines) {
                mText = text + "\n".repeat(minLines - it.lineCount)
            }
            onTextLayout(it)
        },
        style,
    )

}
```

### usage

```kotlin
MinLineText(
    text = "a sample text",
    minLines = 2,
)
```

Comment: For me doesn't work

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS what is the problem? did you test it in runtime?